# Pass data from one date picker to another

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this situation:

2 files (contact.html and booking.php)
On my contact.html I have the following code:

```
<form action="booking.php" method="POST" role="form" class="formular">
    <h3>Online booking!</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" class="form-control" placeholder="Check in" style="width: 258px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="dateToInput" name="dateToInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Check out" style="width: 258px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

On my booking.php file I have the following code:

```
<form>
    <div class="booking">
        <form name="" action=" " method="post">
        <h1>BOOKING</h1>
            <div class="bookingDate">
                <p>Check in:</p>
                <div id="dateFrom">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bookingDate">
        <p>Check out:</p>
        <div id="dateTo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="dateFrom" id="dateFromInput" value= $_POST["dateFrom"] />
    <input type="hidden" name="dateTo" id="dateToInput" value=$_POST["dateTo"]/>
</form>
```

So, I have two calendars on my contact.html page and two calendars on booking.php.
I want that when I choose 2 dates (on my contact.html) form, those exact dates to be passed to the other two calendars that I have on booking.php
Could anyone please help me? I have searched a lot and I can't find an answer.

Comment: Can you concretize your question? In what exactly moment do you want these dates change? After submit or immediately after select two dates on one page.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase the issue that I am having. On my contact.html page, I have (on the left side) 2 date pickers: one for check in and another one for check out. After I choose a check in date and a check out date and press Submit I am redirected to booking.php. On this page I have (on the center of the page) 2 other date pickers that are set, by default, with the today date, both for check in and check out. I want for these 2 date pickers to have the dates that were selected previous on contact.html page so that the user will not have to choose them again.

Comment: Well, the guys below answer you properly. In your page booking.php you will have your values. Just write this values from $_POST to new datepickers in your booking.php.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code to following in value section. Similary for other field as well.

```
<input type="hidden" name="dateFrom" id="dateFromInput" value= "<?php echo $_POST["dateFrom"] ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks Senthil but this didn't do the trick :(. It still doesn't work, the dates are not changing on my booking.php calendars.

Comment: better debug by adding this line in starging of booking.php and see what is the output you are getting <?php echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>"; ?>

Comment: Array
(
    [dateFrom] => 09/21/2016
    [dateToInput] => 09/24/2016
    [adults] => 4 Adulti
    [number_of_rooms] => 3
)

Comment: This looks correct but the ideea is that the dates from the booking.php calendars are not changing, they stay fixed on the 20.09 (today date) even though the data from contact.html is sent correctly. I think it is because are hidden but if I remove hidden, then a normal text box will appear that will print the date I've selected in the contact.html form, and I don't want to print that out. I want that data to "tell" the right date to the calendars in booking.php

Answer (score 0):

Contact has `name="dateToInput"`  yet booking is looking for `dateTo`
Fix one: correct the name of the input in contact

```
<input type="text" id="dateToInput" name="dateTo" class="form-
```

Fix two: You have no PHP tags in your booking code, without them $_POST is not available, nor are those values being printed.

```
<input type="hidden" name="dateFrom" 
id="dateFromInput" value="<?php echo $_POST["dateFrom"];?>">

<input type="hidden" name="dateTo" 
id="dateToInput" value="<?php echo $_POST["dateTo"]; ">
```

Note I also wrapped the `values` with quotes

Comment: Thanks Duane for the advices but, unfortunately, stil it doesn't want to work. I select two dates (for example 20.09 and 23.09) on my contact.html page and after I click submit, I am redirected to the booking.php page where the two calendars are not changing (both are showing the date of today ... 19.09).

Comment: If you move the PHP echos to be within the value=" " for the calendars, it should work. Right now they are populating hidden inputs per your question's exampl code.